# What is the rationale behind change of variables in elliptic curves?

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves

Say we have an elliptic curve in its most general form:

$Ax^3 + Bx^2 y + Cxy^2 + Dy^3 + Ex^2 + Fxy + Gy^2 + Hx + Iy + J = 0$

Many websites say that "through appropriate change in variables," we can write the curve in the following simplified form:

$y^2 = x^3 + ax +b$

First of all I'm curious what that change in variables might look like.

Second of all, I'm wondering why exactly that's useful.

Say we have an elliptic curve in its general form, then we let, say, $y_1 = f(x,y)$ for the change in variables, and finally we have:

$Ax^3 + Bx^2 y + Cxy^2 + Dy^3 + Ex^2 + Fxy + Gy^2 + Hx + Iy + J = -y_1^2 + x^3 + ax +b = 0$,

what exactly have we accomplished? If we consider $y_1$ an indeterminate, we have a new curve.

Is it that we can start proving results for $-y_1^2 + x^3 + ax +b = 0$, and then for each point $(x, y_1)$ we have on this curve, we can translate it into a point $(x, f^{-1} (x, y_1))$ on the original curve?

Comment: This doesn't give an explicit formula, but using the Riemann-Roch Theorem gives a proof (at least for curves over $\Bbb C$) that every elliptic curve is birationally equivalent to one of the given simplified form (sometimes called "Weierstrass normal form"). Note that the above statement is not true over fields of characteristic $2$ and $3$, for which more complicated normal forms are necessary.

Comment: Just like in the case of [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), describing [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), the terms of the form $x^ay^b$ occur as a result of **rotation**, and those of the form $x^a$ and $y^b$ with $a,b<3$ are the byproduct of a **translation**.